# Android Studio Constraintlayout align to the right programatically

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm making a chat app and I'm having some trouble with the layout of my messages. I want the messages send by the logged in user to be aligned to the right of the layout and the messages send by other group members to be aligned to the left.

This is my xml file:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/container_message"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/user_image"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:src="@color/colorBlack"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/container_message_text"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_light"
    android:text="19 juni, 00:32"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/container_message_text"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/container_message_text" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container_message_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingEnd="12dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorTextWhite"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/rubik"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:maxWidth="240dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Picture of the current layout:
[image: Picture of the current layout]

I need the purple messages to be aligned to the right, how can this be done programmatically?

Comment: Use recyclerview with multiview type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better try chat layout using two different layouts for sender's message and yours message and if you are using recyclerview then the following adapter might help you.

```
public class MessageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT = 1;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 2;

private Context mContext;
private List<UserMessage> mMessageList;

public MessageListAdapter(Context context, List<UserMessage> messageList) {
    mContext = context;
    mMessageList = messageList;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMessageList.size();
}

// Determines the appropriate ViewType according to the sender of the message.
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    UserMessage message = (UserMessage) mMessageList.get(position);

    if (message.getSender().getUserId().equals(currentUserId)) {
        // If the current user is the sender of the message
        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;
    } else {
        // If some other user sent the message
        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
    }
}

// Inflates the appropriate layout according to the ViewType
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;

    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.item_message_sent, parent, false);
        return new SentMessageHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.item_message_received, parent, false);
        return new ReceivedMessageHolder(view);
    }

    return null;
}

// Passes the message object to a ViewHolder so that the contents can be bound to UI.
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    UserMessage message = (UserMessage) mMessageList.get(position);

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT:
          ((SentMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
          break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
          ((ReceivedMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
    }
}

private class SentMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    SentMessageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //bind views
    }

    void bind(UserMessage message) {
        //set values
    }
}

private class ReceivedMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ReceivedMessageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //bind views
    }

    void bind(UserMessage message) {
        //set values
    }
}
}
```